Getting black parts of the exported image using Export.toDrive
I am trying to export images from an image collection, the exported image is black with no values appearing in arcgis pro
Here is my code:
polygon = ee.Geometry.Polygon([xMin, yMin, xMax, yMin, xMin, yMax, xMax, yMax],new_crs)
filtered_collection = (
                ee.ImageCollection(collection_snippet)
                .filterDate(start_date_formatted, end_date_formatted)
                .filterBounds(polygon)
                                  )
for i, image_id in enumerate(image_ids):
            image = ee.Image(filtered_collection.filter(ee.Filter.eq('system:index', 
                     image_id)).first())
            new_crs = ee.Projection('EPSG:4326')
            image_projected = image.toDouble().setDefaultProjection(new_crs)
            image_name = image_id + ".tif"
            image_clipped = image_projected.clip(polygon)
            task = ee.batch.Export.image.toDrive(
                image=image_clipped,
                folder='gee_images9',
                description="image_test_new_"+str(i),
                region = image_clipped.geometry(),
                scale = images_scale,
                maxPixels = 1e13
                                                )
            task.start()

